# Sequential procedures in Lisp

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp, common-lisp, racket

When I try to program in a functional style with immutable objects, sequential operations end up being written inside-out, like this:

```
(thing-operation3
  (thing-operation2
    (thing-operation1 thing extra-arg1)
    extra-arg2)
  extra-arg3)
```

I'm starting to see this pattern repeating all over my code, and I find it very hard to read. This could marginally be improved using higher-order procedures like curry and compose:

```
((compose1
  (curryr thing-operation3 extra-arg3)
  (curryr thing-operation2 extra-arg2)
  (curryr thing-operation1 extra-arg1))
 thing)
```

Better perhaps, but it is still written upside-down, and it takes some extra cognitive load to figure out what is going on. And I'm not sure whether this is ideomatic Lisp-code.

Object-oriented style is so much easier to read:

```
thing.operation1(extra-arg1).operation2(extra-arg2)
    .operation3(extra-arg3)
```

It reads in a natural order, and it could also be implemented with immutable objects.

What is the *ideomatic* way of writing such sequential operations in Lisp so that they are easy to read?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An usual way in Common Lisp would be to use `LET*`

```
(let* ((thing1 (thing-operation0 thing0 extra-arg0))
       (thing2 (thing-operation1 thing1 extra-arg1))
       (thing3 (thing-operation2 thing2 extra-arg2)))
  (thing-operation3 thing3 extra-arg3))
```

That way one can name the return values, which improves readability and one could write declarations for those.

One could also write a macro which might be used like in the following:

```
(pipe
 (thing-operation1 thing extra-arg1)
 (thing-operation2 _2    extra-arg2)
 (thing-operation3 _3    extra-arg3)
 (thing-operation4 _4    extra-arg4))
```

Some language provide similar macros and Lisp libraries may provide variations of it. Let's write a simple version of it:

```
(defmacro pipe (expression &rest expressions)
  (if (null expressions)
      expression
    (destructuring-bind ((fn arg &rest args) &rest more-expressions)
        expressions
      (declare (ignorable arg))
      `(pipe
        (,fn ,expression ,@args)
        ,@more-expressions))))
```

For above `pipe` expression the following code is produced:

```
(THING-OPERATION4
 (THING-OPERATION3
  (THING-OPERATION2
   (THING-OPERATION1 THING EXTRA-ARG1)
   EXTRA-ARG2)
  EXTRA-ARG3)
 EXTRA-ARG4)
```

A variant:

```
(defmacro pipe (expression &rest expressions)
  (if (null expressions)
      expression
    (destructuring-bind ((fn arg &rest args) &rest more-expressions)
        expressions
      `(pipe
        (let ((,arg ,expression))
          (,fn ,arg ,@args))
        ,@more-expressions))))
```

This would let you write:

```
(pipe (+ 1000 pi)
      (+ arg1 arg1)         ; use the previous result multiple times
      (+ arg2 (sqrt arg2))) ; use the previous result multiple times
```

Comment: There is a library called `arrows` that implements such things, available from Quicklisp.

Answer (score 3):

Clojure has a threading operator, [`->`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E), which does what you expect:

```
(-> thing
    (thing-operation1 extra-arg1)
    (thing-operation2 extra-arg2)
    (thing-operation3 extra-arg3))
```

You can implement this easily as a macro in other Lisp dialects. Greg Hendershott's [rackjure](http://pkg-build.racket-lang.org/doc/rackjure/index.html) library has a `~>` form that does the same thing in Racket, for example.

The `->` (or `~>` in rackjure) macro splices the result in as the first argument of each subform. If you want to splice the result in as the last argument instead, there's a [`->>`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) macro (`~>>` in rackjure).

Comment: The library `arrows` implements this similarly for Common Lisp.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the [PROGN](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/s_progn.htm) Common Lisp special form.

Or you could define your own Lisp macro to fit your taste.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe the question was unclear, every operation takes a "thing" and some extra arguments, and returns a new "thing", which the next operation should use. I want to chain these operations in a clear and not overly verbose way.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
(reduce (lambda (a b) (funcall b a)) 
    (list thing 
          (partial-apply op1 arg1) 
          (partial-apply op2 arg2) 
          ... 
          (partial-apply opn argn) ))
```

(in [Common Lisp](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_reduce.htm)). In [Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=foldl#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29),

```
(foldl (lambda (a b) (a b))
   thing (list 
          (partial-apply op1 arg1) 
          (partial-apply op2 arg2) 
          ... 
          (partial-apply opn argn) ))
```

Regarding terminology, it's either `((curry fun) arg)` or `(partial-apply fun arg)`.